# Oracle SQL French script file

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus, french

I need to do a mass insert into my database. I have French characters(e.g é) into my table

When i connect to SQLPlus and run the query manually

```
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('é');
```

Data is inserted properly.

When i save the same query in an Sql file and execute same through SQLplus

I get below error:

```
SQLPLUS>@test.sql;
ERROR:
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
```

Can anyone guide me.

thanks

Comment: What is the **exact** content of test.sql?

Comment: Exactly as my insert command: INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('é');

Comment: I have done my research and i have found that I need to change my session NLS parameters. But i want to know exactly what parameters and consequences of those change...If anyone can help me?